# Validators composition in Angular / OR-ing two validators

Tags: angular, validation

I have a login form in my Angular 4 application. In this form I have a "Login" field, which should accept either **E-Mail address** of the user or her **phone number**.

I have a built-in validator for E-Mail address (coming from Angular) and I also have a custom validator for phone numbers.

However, how do I apply both validators to the input field grouping them with **OR** function? i.e. the field should be considered valid if at least one of these validators is valid.

By default Angular requires all validators to be valid.

I'm using reactive forms.

Comment: What about to do it in single regex that accepts an email or a number? So you can just use `Validators.pattern(REGEX)`...

Comment: Check this [**PLUNKER**](http://plnkr.co/edit/lF0gEJj6uNaWnivo2Xdl?p=preview).

Comment: I don't want to mix/duplicate logic of two different validators. The solution should be able to compose existing validators to achieve the desired effect.